# Overriding higher-kinded abstract types in Scala

Tags: scala

The following code shows a shallow hierarchy where a type representing a generic binary operation is used to substantiate a parameterized abstract type in another shallow container hierarchy:

```
trait BinaryOp[A] extends ((A,A) => A)
trait Plus[A] extends BinaryOp[A]
trait Minus[A] extends BinaryOp[A]

trait BaseOps {
  type T[A] <: BinaryOp[A]
  def apply[B](one: B, two: B)(op: T[B]) = op(one, two)
}

case object PlusOp extends BaseOps {
  override type T[A] = Plus[A]
}
case object MinusOp extends BaseOps {
  override type T[A] = Minus[A]
}

object App {
  val plus = new Plus[Int] {
    def apply(i: Int, i2: Int) = i + i2
  }

  def main(a: Array[String]) {
    val exp = Expr(PlusOp)
    exp.bo(1,2)(plus)
  }
}
```

The idea is to be able to state an operation that may be valid for many different types up front, without being tied to a type-specific operation. If I define an expression class generically, all is well

```
case class Expr[T <: BaseOps](bo: T = PlusOp)
```

However for my use case it is undesirable for Expr to to be paremeterized:

```
case class Expr(bo: BaseOps = PlusOp)
```

The following code fails without a generic Expr:

```
object App {
  val plus = new Plus[Int] {
    def apply(i: Int, i2: Int) = i + i2
  }

  def main(a: Array[String]) {
    val exp = Expr(PlusOp)
    exp.bo(1,2)(plus)
  }
}
```

The error:

```
 found   : App.plus.type (with underlying type java.lang.Object with Plus[Int])
 required: exp.bo.T[Int]
   exp.bo(1,2)(plus)
```

This makes it seem as if the type information from the abstract type `T[A] <: BinaryOp[A]` is not being substantiated with the information in the subtype `PlusOp`, which overrides the abstract type as `T[A] = Plus[A]`. Is there any way to work around this without making `Expr` generic?

Answer (score 2):

With "-Ydependent-method-types",

```
def Expr(_bo: BaseOps = PlusOp) = new BaseOps {
    override type T[A] = _bo.T[A]
    val bo: _bo.type = _bo
}
```

But, I don't know what this precisely means...